# mysql average and sum of the date field

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql  table with fields `startdate` , `enddate` ,`product name`  and name of the customer. 
want to find average staying of the customer in one query .
Mysql query

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(HOUR(startdate),HOUR(enddate))), name FROM staybase GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query below will give you the required output :-

```
 
select Name , AVG(time_to_sec(timediff(enddate, startdate )) / 3600) 
from staybase group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using TIMESTAMPDIFF:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, startdate, enddate)) avg_stay_hour
FROM 
    staybase
GROUP BY 
    name
```